# Regex with awk or gawk

Tags: regex, awk, gawk

I'm a beginner user of awk/gawk. 
If I run below, the shell gives me nothing. Please help!

```
echo "A=1,B=2,3,C=,D=5,6,E=7,8,9"|awk 'BEGIN{
n = split($0, arr, /,(?=\\w+=)/)
for (x=1; x<n; x++) printf "arr[%d]=%s\n", x, arr[x]
}'
```

.....................................................

I am trying to parse:

```
A=1,B=2,3,C=,D=5,6,E=7,8,9
```

Expected Output:

```
A=1
B=2,3
C=
D=5,6
E=7,8,9
```

I bet there's something wrong with my awk.

Comment: There is no look-ahead in awk, IIRC.

Comment: Good question with self-documenting test case. Keep posting and Good Luck!

Answer (score 4):

gawk **doesn't** support look-ahead.

if you want **gawk** to parse it as you expected, try this:

```
awk '{n=split(gensub(/,([A-Z])/, " \\1","g" ),arr," ");for(x=1;x<=n;x++)print arr[x]}'
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  echo "A=1,B=2,3,C=,D=5,6,E=7,8,9"|awk '{n=split(gensub(/,([A-Z])/, " \\1","g" ),arr," ");for(x=1;x<=n;x++)print arr[x]}'
A=1
B=2,3
C=
D=5,6
E=7,8,9
```

Comment: Ooh, I like that.  I was trying to figure out how to split, but I didn't think of using `gensub()` and using the backreference to keep the part we want to keep.  +1.

Comment: @steveha thx. the first came up was `sed -r 's/,([A-Z])/ \1/g'|awk 'simple split..'` but I thought it would be nice to write in single process.

Answer (score 3):

This might be easier with sed:

```
$ echo "A=1,B=2,3,C=,D=5,6,E=7,8,9" | sed 's/,\(\w\+=\)/\n\1/g'
A=1
B=2,3
C=
D=5,6
E=7,8,9
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using gnu awk, you could do:

```
awk '{printf $0 "\n" substr( RT, 2 )}' RS=,[A-Z]
```

Comment: I was also thinking of using RS but didn't knew how get that macthed text with RT :)

Answer (score 1):

As nhahtdh, theres is no lookahead in awk... But you can use a different separator for the assignments. Why not "A=1;B=2,3,4;C=5..."?
If your input must have that format, try flex...

Answer (score 1):

You could also use comma as the *record* separator:

```
echo "A=1,B=2,3,C=,D=5,6,E=7,8,9" |
awk -v RS=, '{sep=","} /=/ {sep="\n"} NR==1 {sep=""} {printf "%s%s", sep, $0}'
```

outputs

```
A=1
B=2,3
C=
D=5,6
E=7,8,9
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.  First, you don't want a `BEGIN` clause; you just want this to run on every input line.  Second, you are trying to use regular expression features that AWK does not support.

Instead of trying to use a fancy pattern that splits the string, loop and call `match()` to parse out the features you want.

```
echo "A=1,B=2,3,C=,D=5,6,E=7,8,9"|awk '
{
    line = $0
    for (i = 0;;)
    {
        i = match(line, /([A-Z]+)=([0-9,]*)(,|$)/, arr)
        if (0 == i)
            break
        key = arr[1]
        value = arr[2]
        l = length(key "=" value ",") + 1
        line = substr(line, l)
        printf "DEBUG: key '%s' value '%s'\n", key, value
    }
}'
```

This prints:

```
DEBUG: key A value 1
DEBUG: key B value 2,3
DEBUG: key C value
DEBUG: key D value 5,6
DEBUG: key E value 7,8,9
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way using awk

```
awk '{print gensub(/,([A-Z]+=)/, "\n\\1","g")}' temp.txt
```

Output

```
A=1
B=2,3
C=
D=5,6
E=7,8,9
```